# Populate from Parent to Child

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these 3 models:

```
const CommentSchema = Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario'
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
    },
})
```

```
const UsuarioSchema = Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
})
```

```
const PerfilSchema = Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario'
    },
    especialidad: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Especialidad',
        required: false
    },
})
```

I'm trying to get a list of Comments with Users and Perfil **(in that specific order)**. How can me get that list?

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of comments with users and perfil in that specific order, you can use Mongoose's populate() method to populate the references in the CommentSchema with their corresponding data from the UsuarioSchema and PerfilSchema. Here's an example:

```
const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
const Perfil = mongoose.model('Perfil', PerfilSchema);

Comment.find()
  .populate({
    path: 'user',
    model: 'Usuario',
    populate: {
      path: 'perfil',
      model: 'Perfil',
    }
  })
  .exec((err, comments) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
    }
    // do something with the comments
  });
```

Comment: does it work even when i don't have any virtual from users to perfil?